# subprocess.call doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess

I have the following batch file (test.bat)

```
my.py < commands.txt
```

my.py does the following:

```
import sys

print sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Everything works fine if I launch this batch file from command line (from cmd.exe shell in Windows 7).

But if I try to run it via `subprocess.call` function from python it doesn't work.

How I try to run it from python:

```
import subprocess
import os

# Doesn't work !
rc = subprocess.call("test.bat", shell=True)
print rc
```

And this is the error message that I get:

```
>my.py  0<commands.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.....\my.py
", line 3, in <module>
    print sys.stdin.readlines()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
1
```

I'm using python 2.7.2 but on 2.7.5 I get the same behavior.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused, "try to run it", you say you're trying to run `my.py` but the example says `test.bat`? I'm confused exactly what are you trying to get out of the .bat file and what does the bat file look like? and why not use something other than `.call()` such as `check_output()` which actually returns output?

Comment: @Torxed Everything is there: batch file is called test.bat and I call it from python via subprocess.call. It doesn't behave the same way as it behaves when run from the Windows 7 shell (cmd.exe). Hopefully it is clearer now

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
rc = subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "/path/to/test.bat"])
```

Or using the shell:

```
rc = subprocess.call("cmd /c /path/to/test.bat", shell=True)
```

Comment: I tested all your proposals, they don't work. Any other ideas are welcome

Comment: He's reffering to HOW you call the bat script. `cmd /c test.bat` will execute a cmd shell that executes test.bat, returns the output and dies. And the reason to why he reffers to `shell=True` is because there's two ways of using subprocess, either via spplying it with a STRING as a command but then you have to use `shell=True`, otherwise you must supply a list with more than 1 object.

Comment: See Torxed answer; setting stdin=PIPE seems to make it work, but I'd like an explanation

Comment: @INS When you say it doesn't work, what does it do? I notice that your my.py script is reading from `stdin`, which only works if you are actually giving `stdin` input, like from a live shell where you (the user) are actually typing something.

Comment: I get the same behavior as in my case (see the question). I don't understand why I need to give something to stdin (stdin=PIPE) because the my.py script already has a redirection to a file which should be its stdin (see batch file: `my.py < commands.txt`). Or am I wrong?

Comment: @INS You are definitely doing *something* wrong, I think you are complicating the process you are trying to accomplish needlessly. I suggest you create a new question, instead of asking help with the implementation you have thought of, ask for help to accomplish the task, and you will get better implementations. Then you could ask more questions about those implementations if you need to. To give an analogy, if you are trying to get a stone out of the bottom of a well, and all you know how to do is use a string, it will be hard, someone else could suggest putting your hand down.. and eureka!

Comment: @See my comment on Torxed answer. It is unfortunately not my choice. I am forced to use batch files

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
from subprocess import *

rc = Popen("test.bat", shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
print rc.stdout.readline()
print rc.stderr.readline()

rc.stdout.close()
rc.stdin.close()
rc.stderr.close()
```

I'm not sure why you refer to:

```
my.py < commands.txt
```

Does the input has anything to do with the bat-file?
If so do you call:

```
python my.py
```

which opens the batfile via subprocess that does:

```
batfile < commands.txt
```

or why is that relevant?

Comment: +1 now we're getting somewhere: if I run `from subprocess import *

rc = Popen("test.bat", shell=True)
rc.wait()
print rc.returncode` it has the same behavior BUT if I run `from subprocess import *

rc = Popen("test.bat", shell=True,stdin=PIPE)
rc.stdin.close()
rc.wait()
print rc.returncode
` it works well... any idea why?

Comment: I'm referring to calling the batch file from python, and that batch file contains a call to a python script that uses the file commands.txt as input (stdin redirection in batch file). Clearer now?

Comment: I just can't help to think that you're doing more work than needed.. I'm all for rebuilding the wheel and all that but can't you just skip the batch+py process and just go straight to using the script that the bat file calls? anyway, my best guess is that `PIPE`ing does the job for you and whatever you piped in to the batscript gets transfered downwards, i'm on a train and havn't slept in hours so i'm a bit unsure atm but try fiddling around with it :) Remember that you can also PIPE the output of one rc into another `Popen(".. cmd ...", stdin=rc.stdou)` for instance.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I cannot. This is because the system that I need to use is designed with batch scripts that I need to call before launching any commands... What I did here was just a reduced example to show the problem. Thanks!