# crontab: python script being run but does not execute OS Commands

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have this crontab configuration setup and the following script.

```
MAILTO="abc@avc.com"
41 15 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/atweb/Documents/opengrok/setup_and_restart.py >       /home/atweb/Documents/opengrok/restart_log.txt 2&>1
```

And the python script is as this

```
import subprocess
import os
from time import gmtime, strftime


def main():
    print(strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X +0000", gmtime()))
    print('Running opengrok index..')
    subprocess.call(["cd", "/home/atweb/Documents/opengrok"])
    subprocess.call(["./stop_website"])
    print('Stopped website...')
    subprocess.call(["./index_opengrok"])
    print('finished indexing...')
    subprocess.call(["./setup_opengrok"])
    print('setup finished...')
    subprocess.call(["./start_website"])
    print('Finished opengrok index..')

if  __name__ =='__main__':main()
```

And this is the output log

```
Tue, 27 Aug 2013 22:41:01 +0000
Running opengrok index..
```

For some reason the script has begun running but other parts of the script are not finished.
I am not sure if its OS fault or cron fault or python. The script by itself runs fine when I invoke it from command line.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Instead of redirection, try opening the file for writing (or appending) from within the script? That works for me in a very similar application. Hmm, check your final redirect... should be `2>&1` not `2&>1`

Comment: Try looking into this answer and see if it's your same problem, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16646206/2714534

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need shell to run `cd` command. In your crontab define `sh` or `bash` as SHELL.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO="abc@avc.com" 
# m h dom mon dow   command
41 15 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/atweb/Documents/opengrok/setup_and_restart.py >       /home/atweb/Documents/opengrok/restart_log.txt 2&>1
```

Or open shell as subprocess in python.

Answer (score 2):

Two things: Your `cd` will set the directory for that subprocess, which immediately exits:

```
subprocess.call(["cd", "/home/atweb/Documents/opengrok"])
```

In other words, it's a wasted step.

The next subprocess doesn't know anything about the previous one's environment:

```
subprocess.call(["./stop_website"])
```

...so it won't be able to run.  If you want all of your programs to run in that directory, use:

```
os.chdir("/home/atweb/Documents/opengrok")
```

before any of the `subprocess.call()` lines.