# Run external program when script is run from cron

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, subprocess

I have a python script that works fine when executed from command line. But when I try to run it from cron, it does not work.

```
command = "rsync -avHP --delete --bwlimit=800 rsync://mirror.nsc.liu.se/CentOS/7.8.2003/  /home/me/reposync/centos"
proc=subprocess.run(command.split(), capture_output=True)
```

The cronjob runs. The cronfile looks something like this:

```
PATH=/home/me
40 13 * * * me cd $PATH && ./reposync.py sync 2> /tmp/test.txt
```

But I get this error (yes, twice) from `print(proc.stderr.decode('utf-8'))`:

```
-avHP: rsync: command not found
```

It seems like the problem has to do with not finding `rsync` but I don't know what to do about it.

The output from `/tmp/test.txt`:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rsync'
```

I have tried adding `shell=True` to the `subprocess.run` but it does not seem to make a difference. Or well it does not throw that exception, but I still get the same error when printing stderr from proc.

I suppose that I could solve it by including the absolute path to `rsync` but it feels like it's a bad idea. But I could be wrong about that. If that is the right approach, please explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your crontab, you are overwriting your `$PATH` variable, which now contains only the directory `/home/me`. Your `rsync` executable now cannot be found, since it is not in your home directory.

Change your crontab entry by removing the `PATH=...` line and calling your script with it's full path:

```
40 13 * * * me /home/me/reposync.py sync 2> /tmp/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to define shell in your crontab.
The question has been asked previously.

[crontab: python script being run but does not execute OS Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476757/crontab-python-script-being-run-but-does-not-execute-os-commands/18476968)